# Error on operational attribute creation in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

Actually, in my LDAP, I have a groups ou populated with groupOfNames objects and a roles ou populated with groupOfMembers objects.

I also configured the memberOf overlay to retrieve the groupOfMembers (ie roles) the user belong to in the memberof attribute.

My goal is to have also an attribute memberOfGroup with the list of groupOfNames (ie groups) the user belong to.

In order to do that I created an new schema with Attribute Type definition for memberOfGroup attribute :

```
cn={14}memberOfGroup,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {14}memberOfGroup
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.51127.3.2.2.3
  NAME 'memberOfGroup'
  DESC 'The groups the user belong to'
  EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12 )
```

The problem I have is that when I try to set it as operational attribute is :

```
# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f test.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn={14}memberOfGroup,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: olcAttributeTypes: "1.3.6.1.4.1.51127.3.2.2.3" is operational
```

With test.ldif :

```
dn: cn={14}memberOfGroup,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.51127.3.2.2.3
  NAME 'memberOfGroup'
  DESC 'The groups the user belong to'
  EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12 NO-USER-MODIFICATION
  USAGE DSAOperation )
```

In parallel, I also defined the second memberOf overlay.

The first for roles (work) :

```
dn: olcOverlay={0}memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {0}memberof
olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: groupOfMembers
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: memberOf
```

The second for groups (not work) :

```
dn: olcOverlay={1}memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {1}memberof
olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: groupOfNames
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: memberOfGroup
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong with the creation of operational attribute and the error I have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ldif you have **USAGE DSAOperation**

Operational attributes can be used only by the directory itself, and can't be added or modified by a user. OpenLDAP module *memberof* creates it automatically when a user is added to some group(and also removes when user is removed).

If you want some custom attribute for group membership tracking, then you can create a simple attribute(not operational), but in this case ldap server won't update users' membership automatically.